# File list ubuntu-advantage-tools missing

Tags: xubuntu

When upgrading Xubuntu 18.04 I always get the message: "Warning, File with file list of package ubuntu-advantage-tools is missing". What must I do about it?

Comment: Your question should show the complete output.

Comment: FYI: Are you aware that *flavors* of Ubuntu only come with three years of supported life (five years applies to Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server but not flavors), so you're asking about a release that only days ago reached it's EOL.  (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/ or a UWN - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuWeeklyNewsletter/Issue681#Lubuntu_18.04_LTS_End_of_Life_and_Current_Support_Statuses highlights the EOL notices for Lubuntu/Ubuntu-MATE/Kubuntu/Ubuntu-Budgie; Xubuntu didn't announce EOL but refer https://xubuntu.org/release/18-04/ you'll see it's 29 April)

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. No, I was not aware that Xubuntu 18.04 reached it's EOL. What is the best I can do now? By the way, Xubuntu still runs well, the only warning message mentioned I get is when I type sudo apt upgrade.

Comment: I checked my Xubuntu version and it is:  Xubuntu 18.04.2 LTS release amd 64 , so it should not be EOL, I think.